# Find the intersection between three cycles (or more) with Shapely

Tags: shapely

In Shapely's tutorial there is a nice example (illustrated bellow) on how to find the intersection between exactly two points:

```
a = Point(1, 1).buffer(1.5)
b = Point(2, 1).buffer(1.5)
a.intersection(b)
a.union(b)
```

What it doesn't say though is how to find the intersection between more than three points at the same time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does, see [shapely.ops.cascaded_union](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union). There is no equivalent for intersection, but you just need to accumulate a result:

```
result = a.intersection(b)
result = result.intersection(c)
```

More tricks [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11990/1872).